# JS: how to listen event after template contruction?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm listening for an event with jQuery.on() but it is not working, I imagine is because the DOM element.

Then, How can I listen to the "click" event?

http://jsfiddle.net/QbXLf/

```
$(".myClass").on("click", function(event){
    alert("Not Working :(");
});
```

please HELP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
$('#gallery').on("click", ".myClass", function(event){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/QbXLf/7/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution... hook up the events after adding elements to the DOM

http://jsfiddle.net/jtZ8j/